# How to write unit test for a TypeScript Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

I have a working Lambda function and I'm trying to write a unit test for it. How do I properly mock the `Context` and `Callback` objects to check for the response of the function?

```js
import Game from "../classes/Game";
import HttpResponse from "../classes/HttpResponse";
import { Handler, Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda';
import { DataMapper } from '@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper';
import DynamoDB = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb');

const client = new DynamoDB({region: 'us-west-2'});
const mapper = new DataMapper({client});

const put: Handler = (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
    if (!validateInput) {
        const errMsg = `Missing data in input: ${event}`;
        const response: HttpResponse = {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: errMsg
        }

        callback(errMsg, response);
    }

    const game: Game = new Game();
    game.id = event.id;
    game.name = event.name;
    game.imageUrl = event.imageUrl;

    mapper.put({item: game}).then(() => {
        const response: HttpResponse = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: `Saved new game to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(game)}`
        }

        callback(undefined, response);
    });
}

function validateInput (input: any): boolean {
    if (input && input.id && input.name) {
        return true;
    } 

    return false;
}

export { put };
```

Comment: What are you using for testing? E.g. `jest`, `mocha`, other?

Comment: mocha/chai.

The main issues I'm having are:

1. Creating a suitable mock Context/Callback object to pass in the test, and
2. Getting the response from the callback to validate

Ideally I'd also want to mock the DynamoDB call to make sure the put is happening, etc

Comment: For mocking AWS sdk calls, you can try using `aws-sdk-mock` https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock